# How would one find the Taylor series for $f(x) = x^{3}\cos(x^{2})$ about $a = 0$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Just very unsure how this one would be carried out and simplified. Is it simply taking derivatives? Can it be put into general summation notation?

I am thinking there is something to do with the common series:
$$f(x) = \cos(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}x^{2} + \frac{1}{4!}x^{4} - \frac{1}{6!}x^{6} + \dotsb .$$

I am not sure how this might be done.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Place $x^2$ instead of $x$ in your equation and then multiply it by $x^3$

Comment: It's perfectly legal to substitute $x^2$ for $x$ in the series above.  It's also perfectly legal to multiply the whole thing by $x^3$.  It's "perfectly legal" wherever you have absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $\displaystyle f(x) = \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \cdots$ then $$\cos(x^2) = 1 - \frac{x^4}{2!} + \frac{x^8}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n x^{4n}}{(2n)!} + \cdots$$

and so $$x^3\cos (x^2) =  x^3\left( 1 - \frac{x^4}{2!} + \frac{x^8}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n x^{4n}}{(2n)!} + \cdots\right)$$

All of the above is valid since the taylor series for $\cos x$ converges (absolutely) for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank so much!
So I was wondering. On an exam, how much is enough? when can it be stopped? or is sufficiently justified? Could I stop the series at $\frac{x^4}{4!}$?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you that -- it depends on what sort of exam you're doing, what level it's at, etc... but in my opinion, the very least you'd be expected is to show the general term in terms of $n$.

Comment: Also, a similar problem, with the same technique. Am wondering would f(x) = x^2*sin(x^2/3) as a Taylor Series, would that be:

$$\sin {\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}= x^{2}(\frac{x^{2}}{3}-\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^3}{3!}+\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^5}{5!} -\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^7}{7!}\ldots)$$

Comment: Yep! Perfect $\,\,$

Comment: Thanks so much! these aren't as bad as I initially thought. It's really just memorizing the five basic commonly known series, $e^{x}$, $sin(x)$, $cos(x)$, $\frac{1}{1-x}$, and $ln(1+x)$. And then changing them up where needed.